# Azureファイアウォールの設定

Tags: azure

ファイアウォールの設定について

現象：AzureVMからAzureに接続できない(Connect-AzAccount、送信できないエラー発生)

改善方法：Azureファイアウォール設定を変更

送信元　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　プロトコル:ポート　　 送信先の種類　　　送信先
"AzureVMプライベートIPAddress"　　　80,443　　　　　　　　IP アドレス　　　 *

上記の設定を「ネットワーク ルール」に新規追加しました。Azureに接続できました。(Connect-AzAccountできました。)

質問：
送信先を"*"を指定すると、AzureVMの安全として危険だと思います。
Azureに接続できるように(Connect-AzAccount、Storageaccountの操作とAzureBackupの操作できる)、最低限の送信先を指定したいと思います。
その送信先の設定についてを教えていただけますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

Azure PowerShell を利用してストレージアカウントとバックアップを操作したいということであれば、Azure Firewall のアプリケーションルールで次の URL を許可すればよいと考えます。（動作確認はしておりません）

- login.microsoftonline.com
- management.azure.com

Answer (score 0):

前提が何かおかしい気がします

AzureのAPIをVMから叩くのは本当の目的なのでしょうか。

それはシステムの都合だとして、APIを叩くVMが「Azureのエンドポイント以外にHTTP/HTTPSで接続できては危険」という想定がよくわかりません。例えばOSのアップデートやソフトのインストールはどうするんでしょうか。

その辺はさておいてどうしても他の通信をブロックしたいのであれば、ホスト名ベースでフィルタすることになります。

普通はProxyでURLベースのフィルタをする方がいいのですが、Proxyサーバは任意のサイトにアクセス可能になるので「危険」と言われそうなので、ホスト名ベースでポリシーの書けるサードパーティーのファイヤーウォールを使うことになるでしょう